# TYPO3 - simpler way, rendering content from colPos into Fluidtemplate?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

The official TYPO3 Documentation explains how to create (or copy) and use a `lib.dynamicContent` to render columns into a Fluidtemplate. 
I do not understand exactly whats going on in this example.
The TypoScript there is:

```
lib.dynamicContent = COA
lib.dynamicContent {
   10 = LOAD_REGISTER
   10.colPos.cObject = TEXT
   10.colPos.cObject {
      field = colPos
      ifEmpty.cObject = TEXT
      ifEmpty.cObject {
         value.current = 1
         ifEmpty = 0
      }
   }
   20 = CONTENT
   20 {
      table = tt_content
      select {
         orderBy = sorting
         where = colPos={register:colPos}
         where.insertData = 1
      }
   }
   90 = RESTORE_REGISTER
}
```

I use this snippet in a ton of TYPO3 projects and often had asked myself whats going on there.

I have changed this by experimenting a bit and ended with:

```
lib {
  dynamicContent = COA
  dynamicContent {
    10 = CONTENT
    10 {
      table = tt_content
      select {
        orderBy = sorting
        where {
          data = field:colPos
          wrap = colPos=|
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That seems to do "exactly the same" thing - it outputs my content when called via cObject ViewHelper.

Can somebody explain if or why this is the worse way to render Content?

Here's the link to the `lib.dynamicContent`-doc: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content/master/en-us/Installation/InsertingContentPageTemplate/Index.html#based-on-the-fluidtemplate-content-object-cobj

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

you can try this,

```
# Clear out any constants in this reserved room!
styles.content >

# get content
styles.content.get = CONTENT
styles.content.get {
    table = tt_content
    select.orderBy = sorting
    select.where = colPos=0
}

# Left Column
styles.content.getLeft < styles.content.get
styles.content.getLeft.select.where = colPos=1

# Right content
styles.content.getRight < styles.content.get
styles.content.getRight.select.where = colPos=2
```

Also, you can use variable in the fluid page object, check this out:

```
    lib.pageTemplate = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    lib.pageTemplate {
        variables {        
            content = CONTENT
            content {
                table = tt_content
                select.orderBy = sorting
                select.where = colPos=0
            }

            contentRight = CONTENT
            contentRight {
                table = tt_content
                slide = -1
                select.orderBy = sorting
                select.where = colPos=2
            }        

        }
    }
```

You can find out more here:

- [Adding the page content to a fluid template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081508/adding-the-page-content-to-a-fluid-template?answertab=active#tab-top)
- [Typo3 7.6 typoscript problems with markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46630604/typo3-7-6-typoscript-problems-with-markers?answertab=active#tab-top)

Hope this make sense, Cheer...!

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this snippet together with some information about the Fluid view helper `<f:cObject>` which can be found here: https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/9.5/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/CObject.html

As you can see there are the parameters `data`, `currentValueKey` and `table` that will be handed over to the `typoscriptObjectPath`, which is why the snippet makes perfect sense. The reason is, that it's a bit hard to put the different options into the `where` clause of the `CONTENT` object. So it increases readability and those registers can be easily extended.

So the register in this example is used to put in either the value of the `data` field `colPos` or if that is empty it will take the `current` value from the `currentValueKey` and if that is empty too it will fall back to a value of `0` to make sure the query won't produce an exception.

```
lib.dynamicContent = COA
lib.dynamicContent {
   10 = LOAD_REGISTER
   10.colPos.cObject = TEXT
   10.colPos.cObject {
      field = colPos
      ifEmpty.cObject = TEXT
      ifEmpty.cObject {
         value.current = 1
         ifEmpty = 0
      }
   }
   20 = CONTENT
   20 {
      table = tt_content
      select {
         orderBy = sorting
         where = colPos={register:colPos}
         where.insertData = 1
      }
   }
   90 = RESTORE_REGISTER
}
```

We used a modified version of that snippet to sneak in some more parameter values for the `CONTENT` object.

So we can hand over a data field `pageUid`, if that is not set we will use the `uid` of the current page. This will be overriden if the current or the target page is configured to show content from another page and finally we can trigger a slide with another data field.

```
lib.dynamicContent = COA
lib.dynamicContent {
    5 = LOAD_REGISTER
    5 {
        colPos.cObject = TEXT
        colPos.cObject {
            field = colPos
            ifEmpty.cObject = TEXT
            ifEmpty.cObject {
                value.current = 1
                ifEmpty = 0
            }
        }
        pageUid.cObject = TEXT
        pageUid.cObject {
            field = pageUid
            ifEmpty.data = TSFE:id
        }
        contentFromPid.cObject = TEXT
        contentFromPid.cObject {
            data = DB:pages:{register:pageUid}:content_from_pid
            data.insertData = 1
        }
    }
    20 = CONTENT
    20 {
        table = tt_content
        slide = -1
        slide.if.isTrue.field = slide
        select {
            includeRecordsWithoutDefaultTranslation = 1
            orderBy = sorting
            where = {#colPos}={register:colPos}
            where.insertData = 1
            pidInList.data = register:pageUid
            pidInList.override.data = register:contentFromPid
        }
    }
    90 = RESTORE_REGISTER
}
```

This enables us to make use of the `<f:cObject>` view helper while triggering additional parameters just by handing over some more values within the data array.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Is there any possibility for the `current` to be empty when using f:cObject?

Comment: stdWrap.current will only be set, if you make use of currentValueKey in the view helper otherwise it will be empty, since it is the same as https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Functions/Stdwrap.html#setcurrent